# How to Generate PostgreSql queries from Oracle DB Backup File

Tags: oracle, postgresql, drupal

How to Generate PostgreSql queries from Oracle DB Backup File.Is any free tool available??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Ora2Pg tool](http://ora2pg.darold.net/) will help.